I am trying to add pytest to my test but I got collected 0 items message in terminal
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
import pytest
@pytest.fixture()
def wrong_login_test():
website = 'https://www.saucedemo.com'
path =  "/Users/Bernardo Cabrera/PycharmProjects/Project/resource/msedgedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("Detach", True)

service = Service(executable_path=path)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service)
driver.get(website)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.maximize_window()

username= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="user-name"]')
password= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]')
login= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-button"]')

username.send_keys("username")
password.send_keys("password")
login.click()

badicon = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'error-button')
assert badicon.is_displayed()

driver.save_screenshot('FailedLogin')


You've shown us a file that contains a pytest fixture but no tests, so a result of "collected 0 items" is expected.

This question is similar to: pytest doesn't run any test. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can't use a fixture as a test directly. To make your method collectible by pytest, you should start its name with test_. In your case, keep your fixture, but split your test and call the fixture within the test method.
In your fixture change:
assert badicon.is_displayed()

To:
yield driver

Then create a test method:
def test_wrong_login(wrong_login_test):
    badicon = wrong_login_test.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'error-button')
    assert badicon.is_displayed()

